# API gateway for DB (route all requests to DB)

Tags: amazon-web-services, couchdb, aws-api-gateway

We are using the AWS API gateway to internally forward to some REST API's we have. We have a host: `abc.amazonaws.com` and a server where we have API's: `doSomething()` and `doNothing()`.

We have configured the gateway so we could do: `https://abc.amazonaws.com/doSomething` and it will internally forward to our server where we have the API defined. This works well.

Our goal is we want everything to go thru a gateway and use https. The server behind may keep changing but the gateway configured in our apps should stay the same.

Now, our app also points to a CouchDB server that is listening on port 5984. This DB instance is also running on the same server where the REST API's mentioned above are deployed.

Is it possible to configure the AWS API gateway so that it forwards all requests on a particular port to a specific host? Ex: here, I want all requests coming on https://abc.amazonaws.com port 5984 to go to the server we have on port 5984 (for CouchDB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly **its not possible**. The API gateway endpoints are **only HTTPS** witch is port 443. You can't have an endpoint different than that.

However, for **HTTP integrations**, almost all ports **are supported**:

> API Gateway supports the following endpoint ports: 80, 443 and 1024-65535.

So the closest you can get to your requirement is probably by having a dedicated subdomain for API endpoint, e.g.

```
https://db.amazonaws.com
```

and when you define HTTP integration for it, you can use 5984 port to your db.